# Is it possible to display 2D array as polar plot using Matplotlib imshow()?

Tags: matplotlib

I'm new to matplotlib (and am loving it!), but am getting frustrated. I have a polar grid represented as a a 2D array. (rows are radial sections, columns are azimuthal sections)

I've been able to display the 2D array as both a rectangular image (R vs. theta) using pyplot.imshow() and as a polar plot using pyplot.pcolor(). However, pcolor() is *painfully* slow for the size of the arrays I'm using, so I want to be able to display the array as a polar grid using imshow().

Using pcolor(), this is as simple as setting polar=True for the subplot. Is there any way to display the 2D array as a polar plot using imshow()? without having to do coordinate transformations on the entire array?
Thanks in advance

Comment: I just discovered pcolormesh(), but I'm getting an AttributeError: ravel. Not sure what that means... Like I said, I'm new to matplotlib and I have to say the documentation seems to be lacking :(

Comment: How big are your arrays and is your mesh logically rectangular?

Comment: I've successfully managed to get pcolormesh() working, and it is *significantly* faster than pcolor(). So I won't be needing to use imshow() anymore.
I used x,y=numpy.meshgrid() beforehand to ensure the x,y coordinates and the 2D value data all match up. The arrays are anywhere from 170x314 to 850x1570.

Comment: My experience jives with yours.  pcolormesh() is much faster than pcolor().  You should write up your solution as an answer and accept it.  It will help the web know about the speed differential between the two functions.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

After some research I discovered the pcolormesh() function, which has proven to be *significantly* faster than using pcolor() and comparable to the speed of imshow().

Here is my solution:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

#...some data processing

theta,rad = np.meshgrid(used_theta, used_rad) #rectangular plot of polar data
X = theta
Y = rad

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.pcolormesh(X, Y, data2D) #X,Y & data2D must all be same dimensions
plt.show()
```

Comment: does not work in new version, still need `add_subplot(111, polar='True')`