# PolarColor map plot of grid data in Python

Tags: python, r, matlab, matplotlib

I want to plot a color map of a grid data, grid in polar form. In data, r ranges from 1 to 2 and theta 0 to 360. I want map like this:

[image]
    I plotted like this

```
#x1 of shape(12,)
#y1 0f shape(36,1)
#z of shape(36,12)
fig=plt.figure()  
ax=fig.add_subplot(111) #Output Figure 1
#ax=fig.add_subplot(111,polar='True') #Output Figure 2
ax=fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.pcolor(y1,x1,z)
plt.show()
```

Output:
[image]

[image]

Any idea how to plot the above figure? I also tried converting r, theta into x,y then i got color map in r<1 range which i don't want.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6457331/6935985), `pcolormesh()` is useful for this.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

theta = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 36)
r = np.linspace(1, 2, 12)

R, THETA = np.meshgrid(r, theta)
Z = np.sin(THETA) * R

plt.subplot(111, projection='polar')
plt.pcolormesh(THETA, R, Z)
plt.gca().set_rmin(0.0)

plt.show()
```

[output figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U9lbj.png)

Comment: Thanks bro! i was doing the same, now i checked my data, there is an error in my data

Comment: does this answer your question? if so, please mark the answer as such. cheers.

Comment: I already marked. I was using theta in degree, I changed it into radian, now it's working :)