# How do I draw a matrix round in python?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, matrix, plotly

I have a matrix filled with 0 and 1. I would like to draw it round instead of square. That is, divide the circle into sectors and color them according to the matrix as in this picture:

[image: diagram of matrix/circle relationship]

Each value in this array corresponds to the color that should be filled in the image area. I painted the area pink for clarity:

[image: pink shaded figure]

I managed to create pie slices that I can shade, which works for the sections in circle b for example, but not for the other two:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
x_center = 400 // 2
y_center = 400 //2
img = Image.new('RGBA', (400, 400), 'white') Here's what happened
idraw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
idraw.pieslice([x_center-100, x_center-100,
y_center + 106, y_center + 106], 225, 315, fill='blue')
```

Here's what happened:

[image: current output]

Do you know how to do it in matplotlib or plotly? Theoretically, I understand how to do it, practically-no... Can you help me please??

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6448260/is-it-possible-to-display-2d-array-as-polar-plot-using-matplotlib-imshow) question helps?